# How to get object out of React component

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, axios

I am making an weather app with API, I am successfully receiving the data with API in the function but I am not able to take it out of the function

here is the code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Text, View} from 'react-native'
const axios = require('axios');


let HomeScreen =() => {
  let key = "XXXX"
  axios.get(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${key}&q=London&aqi=no`)
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response)
  })
  return(
    <Text>This is {response}</Text>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: Don't put your personal API key into the code example! Also, what do you mean by "take out of the function"? Can you please expand your example to show what you want to do with the response? Or do you want the response fetching to be outside of the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply return data from the API use a normal JS function, not a React component.

```
function getData() {
  return axios(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${key}&q=London&aqi=no`)
}
```

It will return a promise which you can then use somewhere else.

```
async main() {
  const data = await getData();
}
```

---

If you want your component to *render* data retrieved from the API you need to do things differently.

Use `useEffect` to run once when the component is mounted, and use `useState` to store the data once it's been retrieved. The state will then inform the JSX how to render.

Note that the response from the API is an object with `location` and `current` properties. You can't just add that to the JSX because React won't accept it. So, depending on what value you need from the data, you need to target it specifically.

Here's an example that returns the `text` value from the condition object of the `current` object: "It is Sunny".

```
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise your state with an empty object
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  // Call useEffect with an empty dependency array
  // so that only runs once when the component is mounted
  useEffect(() => {

    // Retrieve the data and set the state with it
    async function getData() {
      const key = 'XXX';  
      const data = await axios(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${key}&q=London&aqi=no`)
      setData(data.data);
    }

    getData();

  }, []);

  // If there is no current property provide a message
  if (!data.current) return <div>No data</div>;

  // Otherwise return the current condition text
  return (
    <p>It is {data.current.condition.text}</p>
  );

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It really helped me a lot!